# Standard for (not) closing Russia-Ukraine war questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Right now it seems rather haphazard:

- [Did a Turkish cargo ship get bombed in the Black Sea during the Russian invasion of Ukraine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/did-a-turkish-cargo-ship-get-bombed-in-the-black-sea-during-the-russian-invasion) NOT closed (also answered).
- [Did a Ukrainian woman tell a Russian solider in Kherson Oblast to put seeds in his pockets so flowers would grow when he dies in Ukraine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53058/did-a-ukrainian-woman-tell-a-russian-solider-in-kherson-oblast-to-put-seeds-in-h) NOT closed (there was at least 1 close vote, but it expired), not answered.
- [Did the Russian 74th motorised rifle brigade surrender in February '22?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53060/did-the-russian-74th-motorised-rifle-brigade-surrender-in-february-22) **closed** (it was a bit confusing as a question, with some quotes only talking of platoon surrendering, not the entire brigade).
- [Does this video show a Ukrainian father saying goodbye to his daughter?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53063/does-this-video-show-a-ukrainian-father-saying-goodbye-to-his-daughter) NOT closed, 3 close votes, expired in the meantime, so open.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/are-there-independently-verified-cases-of-russia-targeting-ukraines-civil-build Mod CLOSEd. Arguably this one has severe scope/form problems.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53066/did-ukraines-army-manage-to-destroy-15-t-72-russian-tanks-in-hlukhiv-sumy-regi **CLOSED**. I think this was the 1st question on this was that was closed, even though it doesn't seem to be substantially different than those that were not closed.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/as-of-february-25-2022-were-13-ukrainian-border-guards-killed-on-zmiinyi-snak This one has been the subject of conflicted press reports for days. Now **closed** and deleted.
- [Did a "KUB-BLA" AI powered "suicide" drone fly into Ukraine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53143/did-a-kub-bla-ai-powered-suicide-drone-fly-into-ukraine) Only 1 close vote after several days.

So, what's the standard for closing such questions?

Comment: Note: The last question was closed by the community within 5 hours of being asked.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be substantially different than those that were not closed" - It expressed doubt over journalist reports, rather than tweets and the like, meaning it will be a lot longer before it is resolved (We need *better* evidence than the evidence quoted in the question.), so closed as Unresolved current event.